# Mapbox.js fly to location (works) and then open the right marker popup (fails)

Tags: javascript, markers

So I've set up this simple map:

```
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.streets')
    .setView([52.15, 5.5], 8);

var myLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(map);


// Add custom popups to each using our custom feature properties
myLayer.on('layeradd', function(e) {
    var marker = e.layer,
        feature = marker.feature;

// (stuff happens)

    marker.bindPopup(popupContent,{
        closeButton: false,
        minWidth: 500
    });
});

// the following is where it all goes wrong:

// Run easings when links are clicked
    var side = document.getElementById('map-ui');
        for (var i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {                 // for all the number of features we have
            var a = side.appendChild(document.createElement('a'));  // add a 'a' child to the side element
            a.onclick = (function(feature, i) {                     // when you click on it
                return function() {     
                    map.setView( [                          // centre the map to the appropriate coordinates
                        feature.geometry.coordinates[1],
                        feature.geometry.coordinates[0]+0.03    // +0.03 puts it a bit to the left, to make room for the tooltip
                    ],12);
```

Here is where I want to open the popup but I'm not sure how to trigger the right marker to open up. For the real life example, visit www.boerenmetwater.nl. The following four examples don't work:

```
                        //marker()[1].openPopup();
                        //map.marker[i].openPopup();
                        //t.openPopup(this);
                        //marker.openPopup();
                    }
            }
            )   
            (features[i], i);
            a.href = '#';
            a.title = 'klik om naar ' + features[i].properties.plaats + ' te gaan';
            a.innerHTML = '<div class = "menu_plaatsnaam">' + features[i].properties.plaats + '</div>';     
            a.innerHTML += '<div class = "menu_titel">' + features[i].properties.titel + '</div>';      
}
```